# Debian isn't capable of sending emails anymore

Tags: email, debian, virtual-machine

My VM-Ware VM running Debian 6 doesn't send emails since I moved to another house with another modem/router. I did a complete reinstall of Debian, but still I can't send email. My network adapter is set to 'Bridged' (with 'Replicate physical network connection state' enabled).
I installed an application that needs to send an email to work properly. But I can't finish it because I don't receive an email at all.

`date | mail test@example.com` on the command-line also doesn't work, so it hasn't something to do with the application.

Do I need to configure my router in order to send external emails from my VM?

Comment: Can the VM contact external servers or is it just mail?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is connected to the internet, and I can visit websites.

Comment: Some things to check: Check the maillog on the debian VM, perhaps your local SMTP server (sendmail?) has the emails queued up because it can't relay them out for some reason. If you changed internet providers then perhaps you need to use your ISP's SMTP server to relay outgoing mail since most ISPs these days block outgoing port 25 (SMTP) connections.

Comment: I don't know what my current mail system is. Is there a way to find that out? My mail log says the connection to the SMTP-server timed out, so there is a big chance I need to configure my ISP's SMTP indeed.

Comment: the simplest way to  check which mail system you are currently running is by connecting to it via telnet, and see what banner it returns to you; something like `telnet localhost 25` returns "220 example.com ESMTP Exim 4.80 Mon, 10 Sep 2012 11:54:04 +0200" on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the mailing-problems!

I needed to do two things:

1. Setting up a SMTP-server for Postfix because my ISP doesn't allow usage of port 25 without using their SMTP-server. See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-smtp-authentication-for-mail-servers/) reference for a how-to.
2. Then I needed to configure a 'send-from adress', because by default emails are sent from a localhost email adress. The SMTP-server doesn't recognizes this as valid and prevents the email from being sent. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/list.postfix.users/NSgncRg3dK0) reference for a how-to.

It cost me almost a few days to solve it, but now I can receive outgoing emails from my Debian system :).